# Load Balancer with Spring WebClient and Consul

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, spring-cloud-consul

Hi I'm building an application which using **spring-webflux** and **consul**. Now I choose **WebClient** for internal service communication. However I don't how make WebClient load balance using service discovery. Is anyway I can archive this?

Here is my service configuration which I want another service to call resource from:

```
spring:
application:
    name: my-test-service
```

Thank you.